# Can I use Mathematica Online kernel to evaluate expressions from java on my PC?

Tags: java, mathematica-online

I know it's possible to evaluate expressions using Mathematica kernel that's on my computer using J/Link. Is it possible to do the same but use the remote kernel that my Mathematica Online uses?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could. For one: Do you know where the remore kernel runs? Do you have access to it by something like rsh?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries But `CloudEvaluate` can do it from Mathematica, so why wouldn't it be possible from Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wolfram Programming Cloud allows you to evaluate expressions, my guess would be in the same cloud in which the Mathematica Online runs. You can make a simple program that runs in the cloud and responses to an expression with an evaluation. To make this web API, run the following code in the Wolfram Programming Cloud:

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"expression"-> "String"},ToExpression[#]&,"String"]]
```

When you go to the returned URL and add an expression attribute to the end, the page shows the attributes value evaluated as an expression. For example the url https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/something-specific-to-you?expression=Solve%5Bx-1%3D%3D0%2Cx%5D (remember to url encode the expression)
returns:
<|expression -> {{x -> 1}}|>

You have to remember though that each API call costs one Wolfram Cloud Credit. With current prices a thousand calls costs 0.30$. https://www.wolfram.com/cloud-credits/